# How do I use JQuery to wrap a specific image (located in the header) in an anchor tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to use tag manager to inject jquery on a site in order to make an image in the header link to a specific page on the site. The code is working almost completely across the board, but not 100% (seems odd to me).

The image:

```
<img class="img-responsive margin-auto" src="/assets/misc/12345/image.png" alt="example" aria-label="example">
```

The JQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="img-link">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("img[src*='image.png']").wrap("<a href='example.com/image-related-page.html'></a>");
    });
</script>
```

The image is a direct child of a div for mobile screen sizes and a list item for desktop screens (dealing with website platform here, which is the reason for tag manager.) what am I doing wrong?

Edit: the image is not clickable after the first visit to a certain page of the site (but works as expected on all other pages). unfortunately, due to me having to do this as a workaround the platform that this website is on, a minimal, complete, and verifiable example isn't really feasible.

Comment: thanks zack im new here

Comment: Welcome @Stephen, you need to describe your problem more so we could help.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki not sure what else to say, can you point me in the right direction of what more info?

Comment: You could tell us what is the part that not working properly, and what is the unwanted behavior?

Comment: If it's not being wrapped perhaps it doesn't exist on page load? Provide a [mcve] that reproduces problem

Comment: I can't see nothing wrong in your code. Have you checked that your `ready` function is reached? Is there any error in the navigator console?

Comment: The code appears to be working: https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/769060/

Comment: @MarioVázquez hmmm... console is saying that jquery is not defined. any thoughts on how it would be not defined on just this one page?

Comment: Could be your script tag is before tag where jquery is loaded...or the page doesn't include jQuery at all or if it is `$` that is not defined could be using `jQuery.noConflict()`

Comment: @charlietfl the script that I added is appearing before the links to JQuery resources for the page in question, but i thought that the document.ready function made it so that didn't matter?

Comment: No because you can't use `$` or `jQuery` before it gets defined and that occurs when the jQuery library loads and defines it. Note for future reference mentioning that error would have been a huge clue at the beginning

Comment: @charlietfl, sorry didnt notice that error originally. also i tried adding $.noConflict(); and that did not work

Comment: the simple answer is move the code shown after the jQuery.js script

Comment: @charlietfl thanks, i switched the trigger in google tag manager to window load instead of page view and that fixed it

Answer (score -1):

If I understand what you are trying to do correctly it is to append an image to an anchor tag. You should give the anchor tag an Id: `<a id="someId" href='example.com/image-related-page.html'></a>` set a variable `var img = $("<img>"); img.attr("src", "image.png");` and then with jQuery you could say `$("#someId").append(img)`

Comment: Huh? this will write the selector as text in `$("#someId")`. Doesn't make sense

Comment: Jake, no, the image is already on the page, and im trying to wrap the image in an anchor tag so that it links to a page on the site. this is working on most pages but there is 1 page that i know of specifically that it is not working on.

Comment: Still backwards and doesn't do what OP's wrap is doing. The `<a>` doesn't exist

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$("img[src$='image.png']").wrap("<a href='example.com/image-related-page.html'></a>");
```

replaced * with $ according to [Attribute Ends With Selector [name$=”value”]](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/)

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to include what you changed and why.

Comment: Why would this work if OP's selector doesn't? The variations are not significant